# My code doesn't want to replace the default bullet of the unoredered list with a custom image

Tags: html, css

I tried to replace the whole bullets with a custom image from the internet of the unordered list (ul) , so I tried this code:

```html
<ul list-style-image: url(https://www.clipartmax.com/png/full/34-343436_small-red-x-mark-clip-art-at-clkercom-vector-online-dollar-sign.png) no-repeat left top;>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>hello1</li>
</ul>
```

But it hasn't changed, and it just shows the default bullet. How would I do this?

Comment: You have syntax error css property should be in `style` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `style="styles here: value of style"`.

The image is really big, which is why it looks broken, try downloading it and resizing it.

Code:

```html
<ul style="list-style-image: url(https://www.clipartmax.com/png/full/34-343436_small-red-x-mark-clip-art-at-clkercom-vector-online-dollar-sign.png)">
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>hello1</li>
</ul>
```

I downloaded the image, resized it to 10x10, and uploaded it to imgur.

Code with New Image:

```html
<ul style="list-style-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/KDuk2H0.jpg)">
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>hello1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: quick question, what size did you ajdust with the photo

Comment: i resized it to 10x10

Comment: last question why when i put it in a folder it doesnt read it . it goes like this `<ul style="list-style-image: url('pic.png')">`

Comment: hm... if it is in current folder use `picName.png`, if it is in folder use `foldername/picName.png` or `./foldername/picName.png`, if nothing works

Comment: it's in the same i put it like i said in the reply above and it doesn't get changed . why ?

Comment: Try using `./picName.png`. `./` is current folder

Comment: lol still not working that's why i'm confused

Comment: huh.. it is in the same folder as html file right, and you are using just the plain html file, not flask or Ruby on Rails or some other web framework?

Comment: if you can't get it working, the best option is to use Imgur or another image hosting service